# CSS class just refuses to work

Tags: css, razor

Dudes, I have a bootstrap file on my mvc with tons of styling and it's working, but when I try to add a custom styling to a custom class, it just doesn't work. Here is an example:

```
<div>
        <form onsubmit="return false;">
            <select id="themeDropdown" name="themeDropdown" class="themeDropdown"
                @*style="border-radius: 4px;
                background: white url('../Content/themes/base/images/dropdown_arrow2.png') right no-repeat; 
                -webkit-appearance: none; 
                -moz-appearance: none; 
                padding-right:35px;
                margin-bottom:2px;
                border:none"*@>
                <option value="Ugly_Default">Orangered & Gray</option>
                <option value="Redmond">W & B</option>
                               .
                               .
                               .
            </select>
            <input id="submitTheme" type="submit" value="Change theme" class="btn btn-default" onClick="return false;">
        </form>
    </div>
```

So when I apply my style directly (currently commented), it works. When i do .themeDropdown in the bootstrap (example below), it doesn't recognize it in "Inspect element". Even when I type it as a class intellisense shows up! What the ...?! Same goes for all my other styles (code is Razor) - scaffolded classes are working fine, and my custom classes are not.

```
.themeDropdown{
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I know there are many topics about that, but most of them have "class starts with number" problem, which is obviously not the issue. Please assist!

FOR THE PEOPLE WITH THE SAME PROBLEM: Your source isn't updated. Switch its folder to app_data for example, then return it in its original folder. That should help.

Comment: So when you 'inspect element' is it simply not there or just not using it? two very different issues e.g is it there but all the point have a line through them? or you cant find the styling in the 'inspect element'

Comment: Simply not there mate. And when I try to assign it to an existing tag and change the existing tag css styling, it doesn't notice it too.

Comment: Can you make a demo?

Comment: What document have you put the CSS code into? are you sure it is being loaded onto the page?

Comment: How can it not be, it's working for all the other classes, including the button below the select (which came with the scaffold)

Comment: So it is in the same document as other CSS which is being correctly loaded? @GeorgiG

Comment: @GeorgiG, offtopic but be careful while posting question on Social sites as you are using bad words. It will affect the answer you will get. hope you will edit. Thanx

Comment: You're missing a `;` at the end of your style property just FYI.

Comment: also try to give style with related id and see its working or not.

Comment: @hjardine yes, that's correct. Even the select menu is getting all of the scaffold css styles, but not the new. The project is built.

Comment: @Leo sorry dude, I'm terribly frustrated when such a silly thing stops my work.
For your second comment - it works. But when I change the css in that id, it doesn't recognize the changes, even after I build the project

Comment: Can you post your stylesheet order please? I reckon you're fighting against specificity which means you need your overriding styles to come AFTER the styles you want to override. For example, load bootstrap.css then load your overriding styles after that. Should work.

Comment: @Nathaniel - styling is the same as the commented one in the first code section. I didn't want to make a "wall of code" thing. Thanks for the support guys!

Comment: Have you tried using the `!important` syntax to see if it just needs overriding?

Comment: It is definately not overwriting problem. The class that I made is not showing up at all when I inspect element. The strange thing is that IntelliSense shows it when I type it in the Razor view...!important is not solving my problem, this problem persists with all my custom classes and all the scaffold classes work perfectly

Comment: You should check if the stylesheet you are referring to is attached to the document and if so, it is up to date. I recently had a problem, when the browser cached the linked CSS and it had used an old version of the file. If you are using Google Chrome, use the "Sources" tab.

Comment: @marcias Thanks a lot! It solved it.

Comment: So the problem was you hadn't refreshed your cache? well spotted @marcias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the solution - check next-to-last comment under my question.

[marcias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/512045/marcias) comment

> You should check if the stylesheet you are referring to is attached to the document and if so, it is up to date. I recently had a problem, when the browser cached the linked CSS and it had used an old version of the file. If you are using Google Chrome, use the "Sources" tab.